# Study of systems of Linear Differential Equations?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, soft-question

Is there any area of mathematics that deals with and formalizes systems of Linear DEs, akin to how Linear Algebra deals with systems of linear equations? Does it provide any insightful results?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and no. There isn't a single field that covers all of it. The closets analogy is probably the study of Dynamical Systems.

In general, we can't find exact solutions to systems of linear DEs. However, for a certain type, called linear dynamical systems, we can solve them systematically. In fact, many of the tools you might have seen in linear algebra (especially eigenvectors and eigenvalues) turn out to play an important role here.

Linear dynamical systems are particularly useful because they can be used to gain insight into non-linear dynamical systems. Even if we can't solve a non-linear system directly, we can sometimes approximate it by a linear system, in a similar way that you might approximate a non-linear function by its tangent line.

There also exists a topic called Differential Galois Theory, which can be used to answer questions like "is it possible to write the solutions to a differential equation using elementary functions?"